# Excel Macros to find the length of the row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel Macros,

I had come across command `ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select` to go to the last row of the table

I am currently using this command to find the total no of rows

```
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select

y = ActiveCell.Row
```

but the problem is for large data the command skips the data, where is a change in data of the next row.

what maybe the possible problem?

(you can see the table 1069 & 1070 the data type is date which is in same format but the code skipped out uncertainly[note: when there is a change in second column] )

```
.
.
.
1068 >  20-08-2012    C0    138225    98.91608138    99.25925926
1069 >  20-08-2012    C0    138226    99.71159982    98.95776825
1070 >  21-08-2012    __    506821       65335U11     0     
1071 >  21-08-2012    C0    100381     0              0
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Are there blank rows in the column you are searching ? If so, you can do the opposite, start from the last row and go up using `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of your worksheet would be helpful to understand your exact problem.

Comment: I am counting the dates here, C0 here is not taken in account for the code, still it is affecting my code

Comment: again specifing there are no blank rows, there are blank rows in the next column,but they are not taken into consideration while using this command :(

Comment: If you run just `ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select`, is it really ending up selecting the very last row?

Comment: It should at-least run that way, but it is not going to the last one

Comment: How about this `y = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

I'm spinning off the comments but you should always use `xlUp` rather than `xlDown` so as to avoid problems with blanks.

Please select a cell in the target column and run the following:

```
Sub findTherow()
Dim y As Integer
With Excel.ActiveSheet
            y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox ("Look what I found:" & y)
End Sub
```